# Asp.Net MVC partial view form post replaces entire page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.Net MVC and I have got a problem with a form.
I have got a partial view inside a view which has go a form inside.

It looks like this:

**Inside Main.cshtml**

```
<div id="Artikel" hidden>
    @Html.Action("_Artikel", Model);
</div>
```

This renders the partial view.

**Controller of the partial view**

```
public ActionResult _Artikel()
{
    return PartialView()
}
```

All of that works fine but when I fire my `Ajax.BeginForm(...)` it replaces the whole view but not just the Arikel Div.

**Inside the partial view**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Artikel", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Artikel" }))
{
    ...
}
```

I read many articles that there is aproblem with jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax not supported in the latest versions of jQuery.

But I really can't figure out why it always takes up the entire page.
Can someone help me? If you need more code ask for it.

Comment: Did you put `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` in the `appSettings` section of the web.config? And `<script src="/path/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>` in the html header?

Comment: Not the key.. Where in the Web.config do I have to add it?

Comment: In `appSettings`

Comment: Did it, thanks a lot!! Put it as the answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you enable the Unobtrusive JavaScript

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in the *appSettings* of your *web.config* file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually you didn't put the link of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js in main layout. check if ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js was loaded. If it's not loaded browser opens partialview as full page. I was facing such problem, and then I put link in the following manner. and it started work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my very old web app the problem was that different versions of jquery were used on the same page.
This is to be avoided in any case, of course. Just mentioning it here so that others may link this error (Ajax.BeginForm replacing a whole page) to a messy JavaScript setup.